# KVM, libvirt, and LVs inside LVs

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm, libvirt

I have a Debian server running KVM+libvirt. The VMs disks are LVs on the host. The trouble is that if I create LVs inside the guests, they are recursively detected on the host and that creates all sort of problems, like the inability to resize or delete properly LVs.

So I added a filter rule to `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` like this, to exclude scanning LVs inside other LVs:

```
filter = [ "r|/dev/dm-*|", "a|/dev/sd.*|" ]
```

Now my problem is : how do I get LVM to rescan only the "real" VGs and LVs? I now have errors like this:

```
# lvs
  WARNING: Device for PV 73C0Ma-sAYV-Aa10-pAHB-ZAZA-3QjH-Rk1eTS not found or rejected by a filter.
  WARNING: Device for PV fcEG5k-BLzO-dbAr-Yw8o-dPw2-1hAk-VyluvW not found or rejected by a filter.
  LV              VG              Attr       LSize    Pool Origin    Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  HaProxy         data            -wi-ao----   20,00g                                                       
  backup          data            -wi-ao----    4,00t                                                       
  database        data            -wi-ao----   16,00g                                                       
  lvol0           data            swi-a-s---   16,07g      stone-web 70,43                                  
  stone-vtls      data            -wi-ao----    2,00t                                                       
  stone-web       data            owi-aos---   16,00g                                                       
  lv0             ftpstorage      -wi-----p-   10,00t
```

The last lv in this case is actually a LV from a VM, not from the host... How do I get rid of it without rebooting the host?

Comment: could you provide some informations about your physical volumes? what kind of disk backend are you using as disk for the vm?

Comment: There is a RAID array used as pv for the vg, split in lvs. The lvs are the disks for the VMs (using virtio).

Comment: but in your quenstion, include the output of pvs in the physical host

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per pvscan man page and RHEL documentation the following should work:
/etc/lvm/lvm.conf

```
global_filter = [ "r|/dev/dm-*|", "a|/dev/sd.*|" ]
```

```
pvscan --cache
```

https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-pvscan/

```
To prevent devices from being scanned by pvscan --cache,
add them to lvm.conf(5) devices/global_filter.
The devices/filter setting does not apply to system level
scanning. For more information, see:
    lvmconfig --withcomments devices/global_filter
```

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/lvm_filters

Comment: I've tried pvscan --cache, pvscan, vgscan -ay and vgscan -an, no dice. lvs, vgs still outputs the same error.

Comment: Did you update your config to `global_filter` instead of `filter`? What does `lvm dumpconfig` show?

Comment: How does the output of `blkid` look like?

Comment: Ah yes my bad, with global_filter the problem is solved!